# nth:child выбор конкретных элементов (8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 24, 26 ...)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Есть 25 дивов, каким образом можно выбрать определенные дивы (8, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 24, 26) и т.д?

Comment: .class:nth-of-type(№) и так сколько потребуется через запятую

Comment: Если вы ищете какую-то формулу, чтобы все сразу охватить, а не перечислять через запятую, то, скорее всего, такой не будет.

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что это именно только блоки друг с другом, без других элементов... и имеют одного общего родителя, на них можно будет тыкать по конкретному номеру:

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px; height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  margin: 5px;
}

.test:nth-child(8),
.test:nth-child(10),
.test:nth-child(12),
.test:nth-child(15),
.test:nth-child(17),
.test:nth-child(19),
.test:nth-child(22),
.test:nth-child(24),
.test:nth-child(26) { background: #800; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="test"></div>
</div>
```

При этом, nth-child это именно про элемент общего родителя... если среди этих блоков добавить какой-либо еще другой, числа уже будут означать другие элементы (но всё еще можно будет тыкнуть на нужный, изменив числа).

Но если такое дело... можно уж добавить еще один дополнительный класс, именно тем блокам, которые вам нужны. И писать отдельный стиль именно для этого класса.

Comment: nth-of-type правильнее будет наверно

Answer (score 0):

с :nth-of-type()

```css
.test:nth-of-type(2n+8){
  /* Свои стили */
  background: cornsilk;
  color: black;
}
```